# Is there a way to access and edit Apple's Reminders.app database from Android?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Reminders.app for Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/66963/reminders-app-for-android)

> Questions seeking app recommendations, device recommendations, or
>   other purchasing advice are off-topic as they become obsolete quickly.
>   Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're
>   trying to solve.

Uh... ok, fine.

*"Is there a way to access and edit Apple's Reminders.app database from Android, I didn't find a way to do it, how can I do that?"*

Would re-phrasing it this way be ok?

I really am trying to solve this problem, why am I not allowed to do that?

Please notice that "which app is better for this" is one thing (subjective), but not being able to find even one is quite different (objective).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the new phrasing of the question is better, I'll reopen the question. I still fear that the answers will become obsolete quickly, since all solutions depend on specific apps, but at least you'll get some solutions.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. I'd say that as long as the answer is non-obvious and objective, it's IT.